# Facebook Events for syncing in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, events

From few days , I am facing problem in getting Facebook events in iOS, I did not Send App for Review to Facebook and its working fine from same account ,Android person is getting Events. I have checked on latest iOS 8.3 and same on iOS 7.

Why such scenario is occurring in iOS?

I am following below code and it was working cool.

```
NSString* graphPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?fields=cover,name,start_time,end_time,owner,description,location,venue&since=%@&access_token=%@",endTime,[AppHelper userDefaultsForKey:@"access_token"]];
```

This request providing me a dictionary of events.

Please Help and guide me.

Comment: What problem you are facing ,can you explain?

Comment: Now , I am not getting events. But Android is working.

Comment: You are the admin or developer of the application on Facebook developer?

Comment: Can you post that code where you are requesting for facebook permission?

Comment: I am the developer of Application.

Comment: NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_events",@"basic_info",nil];
 [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
 FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
  { [AppHelper saveToUserDefaults:[[FBSession.activeSession accessTokenData] accessToken] withKey:@"access_token1"];
 [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];                    }];

Comment: Can you provide more debug information? What is the exact response you are getting from the API. Do you get an error message? Can you modify your question and show how you actually perform the request? Now you've just created the path for the call, but not executing it.

Comment: I got my answer after debugging as I have to change Graph API. I was using  version 1.0 of Graph API.